# Saving data generated at each iteration in multidimensional array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this code:

```
for h= 1:length ( bb1{CH(i)})
    for k= 1:length(  bb2{CH(j)})
         if NN(bb1{CH(i)}(h),bb2{CH(j)}(k))==1                    
           d = [bb1{CH(i)}(h),bb2{CH(j)}(k)]
         end
    end
end
```

When I run this code, the value of `d` takes the value of the last iteration. I want to save its value for all the iterations. For example, I want to have a `rows_nb` by 2 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly unoptimized code, but the reason is pretty obvious.  Your code is assigning to `d` at every iteration in that code and it keeps overwriting itself.

As such, you need to **append to `d`** if you want to save all of the values in the matrix.  Therefore, do this:

```
for h= 1:length ( bb1{CH(i)})
  for k= 1:length(  bb2{CH(j)})
      if  NN(bb1{CH(i)}(h),bb2{CH(j)}(k))==1
        d = [d; bb1{CH(i)}(h),bb2{CH(j)}(k)]; %// Concatenate
      end
  end
end
```

---

This way, you are adding two columns every time to the matrix and add an additional row at each iteration.